# undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass [RAILS 7]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, I'm trying to upload a profile picture for new users.
here is my information_client_controller.rb

```
# GET /information_clients or /information_clients.json
   def index
     @information_clients = InformationClient.all
  end

  # GET /information_clients/1 or /information_clients/1.json
  # def show
   #end

  # GET /information_clients/new
   def new
     @information_client = InformationClient.new
  end

  def information_client_params
    params.require(:information_clients).permit(:image)
  end

  # GET /information_clients/1/edit
  # # def edit
 # end

  # POST /information_clients or /information_clients.json
   def create
     @information_client = InformationClient.new(information_client_params)
   end
```

here is my information_controller.rb

```
class InformationClient < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :image
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
    content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']},
    size: { less_than: 5.megabytes}
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240"}
    belongs_to :account
end
```

here is my create_information_clients.rb

```
    class CreateInformationClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
      def change
        create_table :information_clients do |t|
          t.references :account
          t.string :pseudo
          t.string :image
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

here is my Page.html.erb

```
<%= form.file_field :image, hidden: true, id: "MyFile"%>
         <%= image_tag ("Profile image.jpg"), onclick: "myfunction()"%>
         <% if @information_client.image.attach? %>
         <%= image_tag %>
          <% end %>
```

here is my Page Javascript file :

```
  const profilepic = document.getElementById("MyFile");
              function myfunction(){
                profilepic.click()
              }
```

i don't where the error comes from since i'm new to app developement, I may have done some confusing code.

Comment: I just think you need to have `params.require(:information_client).permit(:image)` instead in the controller. Note the "s" missing, you are retrieving it for a singe client and params will be called in singular.